# Need help in getting default SharePoint online URL for new SitePage

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, administration, modern-pages, sitepages

I have a requirement to place a button on a page. While clicking the button it will take the user to the the new site page creation page in edit mode where user will directly update the contents inside the page.

The functionality should be implemented through out of the box feature.

I need the default generic URL of that. I can see if we manually try to click on 'New > Site Page' from inside the Site Pages library, it redirects us to below URL, where the `.ASPX` page name is dynamic and always changes each time we try to create a new site page.

```
https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/site1/SitePages/4akm35mp.aspx?Mode=Edit
```

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use URL in below format for your button:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/_layouts/15/CreateSitePage.aspx
```

It should create a new modern site page in Site Pages library for your SharePoint site.

I just tested this in our SharePoint Online site and it worked for me:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. I got that. One quick question on top of it. Can we pass any query string on that URL to directly set some properties value , meaning for example while redirecting the user to above URL I want the category field/property set to xyz value. once the page published automatically the property gets set.

Comment: Unfortunately, No.

Comment: Please [accept my above response as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. Thank you!